# How to bind to encoded image in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

src.bind to ThumbNailPhoto in the JSON

```json
{
 "@odata.context": "http://localhost:35027/odata/AdventureWorks/$metadata#Products",
  "value": [
    {
      "ProductID": 714,
      "Name": "Long-Sleeve Logo Jersey, M",
      "ProductNumber": "LJ-0192-M",
      "Color": "Multi",
      "StandardCost": 38.4923,
      "ListPrice": 49.99,
      "Size": "M",
      "Weight": null,
      "ProductCategoryID": 25,
      "ProductModelID": 11,
      "SellStartDate": "2001-07-01",
      "SellEndDate": null,
      "DiscontinuedDate": null,
      "ThumbNailPhoto": "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",
      "ThumbnailPhotoFileName": "awc_jersey_male_small.gif",
      "rowguid": "6a290063-a0cf-432a-8110-2ea0fda14308",
      "ModifiedDate": "2004-03-11"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's three ways you could do it:

https://gist.run?id=e4d55a8a596bcf9d480c92ec22825597

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./data-uri-value-converter"></require>

  <h3>binding expression</h3>
  <img src.bind="'data:image/gif;base64,' + data.value[0].ThumbNailPhoto">

  <h3>string interpolation binding expression</h3>
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,${data.value[0].ThumbNailPhoto}">

  <h3>value converter binding expression</h3>
  <img src.bind="data.value[0].ThumbNailPhoto | dataUri:'image/gif'">
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  data = {
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:35027/odata/AdventureWorks/$metadata#Products",
    "value": [
      {
        "ProductID": 714,
        "Name": "Long-Sleeve Logo Jersey, M",
        "ProductNumber": "LJ-0192-M",
        "Color": "Multi",
        "StandardCost": 38.4923,
        "ListPrice": 49.99,
        "Size": "M",
        "Weight": null,
        "ProductCategoryID": 25,
        "ProductModelID": 11,
        "SellStartDate": "2001-07-01",
        "SellEndDate": null,
        "DiscontinuedDate": null,
        "ThumbNailPhoto": "R0lGODlhUAAyAPcAABQlZ/z8/J+fnyxLZ87OzuTk5Dtliqqqqiw0WMrKyvDw8EdXpRAYLsbGxubm5urq6qSkpO7u7uLi4mlmZa+vrxAhNiJai4iVqtLQ5rGxsY2v0zMzNfr6+i5zsiVLcmNwmLK8yHZ1esLCwhhHnfb29lB1rDIWcBdQofj4+H6OnfT09Li4tx07iCYlJt7e3qeotNra2o2NjTRcqCM0dQw2WxpTiCk0ZyxDXs/Q0BZkqvLy8hZamBlIhUWBt4enxVNLRpGRkRE/a1NXdRszlN3d3bS0tNfX15qamTI0PT4+PhYYHRkuWVdUUjE0Rw8aSCRUf9TU1GmGpn2lzIeCfsfG2RdhqVdPSkxcg5WVlMzR2Bk/maWhnKyppk5IRCxYmgUGCFBjfNDQziYuY5qYlpKNiRgpQpKOnx5RmTJqnCgtOOHg30U8OKGhoWdbd6iop5WUkjV5tUlCPTlaiM3Ny+Xk4nVzcLa2ttPT0i06SpeWlYyJhrq2sx88WLq6ur+9uqyxvcC+u+fm5NjY2HN9urGtqTlDet/f3zpMlicvSIuHhNXV0mBZVMrJxiw/VNDOy+no5z0nary6uLa0sLOxr6ysqwwqVAULFry9vdTS0MjHx+/v716VxRlenxgwgQwSHdvZ1+7u7Ovr6+Hh4drZ2WhiXk86dpm82htJkn54cw8PD7+/v/7+/r6+vujo6O3t7RZnrOzs7BZZpWuYxsvZ6hhMn+np6VNeqWFpr/39/R0/kCI+dylusLm5ue7t7PX08xlToMzLyu3t7OTj4TkxLvX19cfMz6SioOnp6BVIkTAOe2CBvG+KwSpjn4+Rxba1tA4vTMPCwNHR0Xt/pvv7+3BvfG9saWhtfDVZeN/e3K2rqOrq6erp6Onq6p6yxOfn5zxRaTJJan6Fv8DAv6iloh0eIMrN5KKfm/v8/NbW1SsrLPf4+CJgp/f391BRUvj490FBUfHx8ZmUkD50pdzb2zEgVC0uWz9KizE8ej0jdDAcYhZgqDU4PC8vL3OcxgAAAP///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAABQADIAAAj/AFX9G0iwoMGDBlcpXLgKl0NcASJOm8ahIgp27EgQU6ECngJNrmA9aOWggARDRGAYgRKNQIIGIljxKkLhAAQBAhHq3PmP4cKHECVStIhRI0ePIEWSNIlSJUuXMGXStImTp9WEPhsGDTBxYkUOFzNu7Pgx5MiSJ1OubPky5syaN3NevcrQYYBzX8HqRUFU7NGyStE2XQvV7dS4c+dq5YqiwTwFc16IC9ZLgQ5i6tSFNUo26Vmmap+2lQq3amKeCs8FM4MvXzITJpK9pmdmDrZAvS6T0DgWqdmlaZ2yjfqWqtzTWKcVu4BmRj58bUqVguR6gA1pHyJ9ohNKgYqxnX8L/w493HDp48h7rgrwJ4oUGXA8NIEdoo2JfDOeIGgWa8cVCoqo8UgEOqigg2+BgSZcYaQZl95ACrEnhxa7aLCAAU80gkQ9NuRTzwa6gJGEELHoo8UpKTgT4DYRwIPgZ8ERNlpxiKXX0B9o6DMChT7ccAMnOfCByDUI2LABJ7KAsM+PWtAihRcp+IGOBKFoYqV4CspI3GGmnbaKAtIMUoWOWjDTDhI7vJJDDf6kkoQ/ulQhyyxy7OMBC07K0EMZk4RhSC2uRIBljKJteR5yq7hyzwJi6jgDEhvwkIOasaTiTxJf8CDnLB14YMENefbgyQQrzPGnK4MOVqh5DnoZgxO2iP/JCQ83bFDICJPmEEsFl6ZywqYdnODBDXhEsY48TrQAQSR3SPAALAkSWl6DNSoWwD4MxFqDDb8MQI0tuFK6xKVK/DpnsIfg0YQu4IAjRhl1HNCAIA6EEgqMqk5LY5d0zUOOJ/YIsQG331ABbq6x6HJpBeZyesICIax7gyc2DJCEACvgIEot9wKXL4P7ordTQzEg0gIAMwx8xgcYHEzpKV8kwTCwD2sgsRI2eMBADAeIMIoDD+BLHshciqxTQ00ggAQDKdswwy0YDFICHJtsEgstqfAz87k1N6JLI+TkjEcXbPASjQS11OLx0DMWndgqoTihtBNibIDAEFCXs4wppuj/SguvSzQc7AIa1HBDGfzk3EgaR1CQyTwOqD3egm0fOlcAAgCgNAsMINEJ3hiEowwcu1g9Qhn+BE4z4a9YUMHAHuDxRQwQsIJOAa2sTbmhrVrV0ASaI5FLBZ+D7rLf46rONev6MAB7Gv60M0YGpnrjzeRaslotahEo8QUiwj/BwBDGh+v3DKkLXvMrPPABO6+p6GEMNDAUcH2Wq1LL7064uOGPP0oIHzkAUD6E0UJhynMY6ypQA9hZyh9MIMMkoiEKB2AvfyGjCy668D9/pCEXT9iAJToBteNdjQX+YIH6FmiBgd2ggy1AhTkyQYQC2FBaRLMc9x7YJhAiIR0MKKH5/66mCwZoYYUaCMIzWmgDJXRwDaQggx8EYUP86cttvlNHHTroDwCEcANKEELLhnhAABxxdRdQwgCY+IX/pSIOi5jCHqZ0w49VrncjYwcd3vS/L3wRjAYj4xI6cUauHaIF+1jjBnj1v2GsYRGJiIQRJFBHtvFue0dDQSD80IIOKmEDoGyEEExIiyUMoZAOY0A6kKDINgJwDXEgRTygMY8q4vCOmETIKqYBCkyQgYctAOUAnnGPISLjc6jsADI+uYE1kqOPa1iDFVCRjTCowYJWzCEej4YLXwgDEFvsozAt4IkhBkELpxRcBfghTA+4kh9x6MIE4gGI+mHzlpfc39Gmof+AT+xhER0kRzMtkIZKGBCdqOSD+4Rpif+RowtdiKMkMIG7++FTe/rU5SrcEQpMZCMOHeTHGpGghDT5DaHmukAlvogtN1rhB9PcQiZc4A3JZROXGdUlLtixDUdsoZMAHCkCKkApWqC0CiUgBwhBmY4+vtQK1RgDIH4WNN1lT39GO1oAiBEIRqCig3ywABIQgAganDSdO0hF+EDpyjjAlBR6mGgBHtCxC15Rh9byZh4s0UZLPGGsHmDg1VBaCfAt9YFO6MIPFoGKcQBDDdyARV1vms+sjmwaOoDGFwDwvzLsox4DaAQY1mHUU3qhDEoD4TO/cM4uWGECZIjEKLyBqmj/2bGyNloFCrThjyE44X/pQAAYXuCDwZ6yBH+4gfCC4I8v1CAHWngHY83BCAnAQlC2tSRGLTuyACggHQRkgD9aEINuwOGsR+zBJayRC75GQU1aQMIEpsAFRzjAFZ6xKgaxiChcqGAfBLTFBP5QgoOmswr9yAIE9mEPDaipE6moAxkIEYb75teu2szlXHBBggk4AW9UWAAZjzqnHpyBdTmowD6m8IY+WThV2sXqg/6x0xB8WIgGTub6duCPaujhCM64w4uzu7vtzngVHMiAJQpYVBIr0ME02IAeYiCASxihFRG4MGWN/CAkF2HJOG7ygZfnYEtMIAZvcINjQpFlGBdZ/8Zd5mdvw4xewfHgHlEIQipiEIMjUK8A+NXyReFsowDoIBVyA+MNDMBoHnLRjS1oQTpIEQMg1E4QrbCSoG/L5UITYwWkYEI7qgEEILzhDXnAwqlLzWpW87nSAigCMEQBCwUARmhvzuCMd1qLaNiBDanOQx7GMIYjHKHYxk62sgXAhgw0AAaZfpF+77pNL3FAAS7IhB0o4QY3cCEblCAEJShA7nJn4NwZKIIdLpEAKrZI2hjGKXdREwASwMIQd3hJJhgBDGDMwREEwIHAcRCNaNzh4HdABwxEgWV4HOjW085wTjU4DRJoohZVtN8jjnGMVqTt4yCvxbNaVKCHbzrG+0CigCpWzvKWu/zlK7/EJfqwgprzog84z7nOb86Lnvu8Dz7nRc3tYAdnFKEIGSg3JShxgG5DAAJsEICxx4CFUgcEADs=",
        "ThumbnailPhotoFileName": "awc_jersey_male_small.gif",
        "rowguid": "6a290063-a0cf-432a-8110-2ea0fda14308",
        "ModifiedDate": "2004-03-11"
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

**data-uri-value-converter.js**

```js
export class DataUriValueConverter {
  toView(value, mimeType) {
    return `data:${mimeType};base64,${value}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like option 3 so I'm gonna steal it and use it in my talk next week 

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. That was really useful for my project. Method 1 (binding expression) worked flawlessly. Method 2 (string interpolation) also loads the image, but previously generates an error message in console: `GET data:image/jpeg;base64,${imgB64} net::ERR_INVALID_URL`. I am using method 1, very simple and without errors.